# How can I write to a txt file of my output using python?

Tags: python, file

So I scanned my folder then printed it to my text file, but I dont know why it only gives me 1 output, and that output is the last namefile

```
import zipfile
import os

def out_fun():  
    for x in os.listdir('C:\Users\Guest\Desktop\OJT\scanner\samples_raw'):
        print x
    return x
output = out_fun()
file = open("result_vsdt.txt","w")
file.write(output)
file.close()
```

my only output in my txt file is:

```
fe8c341de79168a1254154f4e4403857c6e79c46
```

which has to be:

`ed64498d29f40ccc07c7fbfa2a0a05e29763f5e2
ed66e83ae790873fd92fef146a2b70e5597792ee
ef2f8d90ebae12c015ffea41252d5e25055b16c6
f4b8b762feb426de46a0d19b86f31173e0e77c2e
f4d0cc44a8018c807b9b1865ce2dd70f027d2ceb
f6c9b393b5148e45138f724cebf5b1e2fd8d9bc7
fa2229ef95b9e45e881ac27004c2a90f6c6e0947
fac66887402b4ac4a39696f3f8830a6ec34585be
fcbbfeb67cd2902de545fb159b0eed7343aeb502
fe5babc1e4f11e205457f2ec616f117fd4f4e326
fe8c341de79168a1254154f4e4403857c6e79c46`

Comment: you iterate across os.listdir and write the restult each time to x, but you return only the last x in the function out_fun(). You should collect all the x in a list and then join it.

Comment: You are returning only the last `x` value (after the end of `for` loop) from your `out_fun`. Try returning `os.listdir('C:\Users\Guest\Desktop\OJT\scanner\samples_raw')` instead of `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it is a little better, it uses less memory and you don't need to create a list or load all the file content in your function:

```
import zipfile
import os

def out_fun():  
    for x in os.listdir('C:\Users\Guest\Desktop\OJT\scanner\samples_raw'):
        yield x

file = open("result_vsdt.txt","w")
for line in out_fun():
    file.write(line + '\n')
file.close()
```

Edit:

It is also better to use `with` when opening file, like this:

```
with open("result_vsdt.txt","w") as file:
    for line in out_fun():
        file.write(line + '\n')
```

it will close the file automatically.

Comment: NameError: name 'output' is not defined

Comment: @jeremydevera Fixed. it was a typo.

Comment: That `yield` is so important when we have a large list of lines. if you find my answer helpful, please check the green one.

Answer (score 2):

## Why is only the name of the last file written to the result file?

Because while every value of `x` gets printed in the `out_fun` function, only the last one is actually returned. You need to store the others somewhere and return them to.

## How to return all contents?

Create a string named `output`, append every value of `x` to it and then return it:

```
import os

def out_fun():  
    output = ''
    for x in os.listdir('C:\Users\Guest\Desktop\OJT\scanner\samples_raw'):
        print x
        output += x + '\n'
    return output

with file = open("result_vsdt.txt","w"):
    file.write(out_fun())
```

`'\n'` is the new line character. That makes shure, that every filename is on a new line.

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'output' referenced before assignment

Comment: I have updated my answer, can you please try it with the full example I provided

Answer (score 0):

Your for-loop will iterate through your files and end with the last file. That means, x will always be your last file.
If you want to return all files, you need to create a list and save all of them there like:

```
def out_fun():  
    array = [""]
    for x in os.listdir('C:\Users\Guest\Desktop\OJT\scanner\samples_raw'):
        array.append(x)
    return '\n'.join(array)
```